# I don't know about bluetooth output via 3.5mm jack

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I am using Raspberry pi 3 in project.

I have a smartphone and Raspberry pi connected via Bluetooth,

and I want to listen to music and calls(HFP) through a 3.5mm jack.

However, the music plays well, but the output is continuously interrupted,

and the call not hear the other friends voice.

Howd do I keep on coming out without breaking the song

and let the other persons vocie be heard??

Comment: Just to be clear, are you listening to the sound through a jack on the phone or on the Pi?

Comment: When I was calling my phone, I confirmed that my smartphone(Android) was connected to Bluetooth.

Comment: @Chenmunka I want to listen the Pi

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Bluetooth is a wireless connection.  The 3.5mm jack isn't.  You can't use both at the same time.  Turn off or disconnect the Bluetooth on your phone, and disconnect from the Pi.  Now, plug in your phone into the Pi's 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But I want to make a call through 3.5mm Pi.
Have you ever seen a handsfree attached to a car?? 
I would like to implement bluetooth to listen to music and 
 make a phone call from a single button when it comes to the phone.

Comment: You want to plug your Pi into your car to play music?  I'm still wondering what you want your phone to do.